# Riemann Integrable Sequences of Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Find a sequence of Riemann integrable functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,1]$ that converges pointwise to $0$, but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^1}$$ does not exist.

I am completely stuck on what do to with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define $f_n$ to take a BIG value on an interval of small length (so that $\int |f_n|$ is big) and the value $0$ elsewhere. Be careful to do this in such a way so that you have pointwise convergence of $(f_n)$ to the zero function everywhere in $[0,1]$.

See below for a solution.

Let $f_n$ take the value $n^2$ on $(1/n,2/n)$ and the value $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence defined by $f_{n}(x)=-n^{2}x+n$ for $x\in(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and $f_{n}(x)=0$ for $x\in\{0\}\cup[\frac{1}{n},1]$ if $n$ is odd and $f_n(x)=\chi_{(1-\frac{1}{n},1)}(x)$ if $n$ is even. For all odd $n$ we have $\vert\vert f_n\vert\vert_{L^{1}}=\frac{1}{2}$ but for all even $n$ we have $\vert\vert f_n\vert\vert_{L^{1}}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Hence for one subsequence of the natural numbers the limit tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ while for the other subsequence the limit tends to $0$. This shows the limit does not exist. Each function is Riemann Integrable by the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability. For $x=0$ or $x=1$ we have by the above definition that $f_{n}(x)=0$ for all $n$. For all other $x$ we simply note that for large $n$ $x\notin(0,\frac{1}{n})\cup(1-\frac{1}{n},1)$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=0$.